# List files of public folder in Google Drive

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

My application wants to list the files of Public folder in Google Drive without any authentication.

How can do it through Java Google Drive library?

Comment: hey, did you find a way? thanks
simple link is working good, but how it can be done from the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User still [needs to be authenticated](https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth) (= logged in) to access public folders.

Comment: How is it going to happen? Will I have to ask for API keys from the person whose drive I am going to access?

Comment: @JamshaidK. API key is your key, not the one from the person whose drive you are trying to access. Alternatively you could use OAuth so the authenticated client is the user of your app rather than you yourself